# How to configure NAT between 2 private network ? CISCO routers

Tags: cisco, router, nat, access-control

[image: This image is a simple network consisting of 2 private networks connected over 1 public network]

If anyone can help with configurations it will be helpful

Comment: We're not here to build entire configurations for you. If you share the current configuration, what you've tried and what problems you ran into we can help solving the problem.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want transparent access both ways you need to avoid NAT and set up a tunnel to connect the networks, preferably a VPN connection. Make sure each side knows the networks/routes for the other side.

Answer (score 0):

As Zac67 said, a tunnel suits your use case better. Here is an example with GRE on your router1:

```
 interface tunnel0
   tunnel source 12.0.0.1
   tunnel destination 12.0.0.2
   ip address 192.168.3.1 255.255.255.252
   no shutdown
 ip route 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0 tunnel 0
```

Remember that GRE does not provides encryption. You can use IPsec for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The best and possible option are

1. connect two networks with point to point leased line and Configure static route on both sites
2. connect two networks with ISP can configure IPsec site -Site tunnel to smoothly exchange traffic between two sites .

3 ) connect two networks with ISP can configure ipsec- GRE tunnel .

Even natting can be done at both ends to access resource of 192.168.2.0/24 from 192.168.1.0/24

Destination natting should be configured at server hosted sites . And PAT need to be configured on 192.168.1.0/24 subnet end

So with destination natted public ip address  servers resources can be access from 192.168.1.0/24 subnet network.